# How to be notified when new Ruby or Rails releases are made?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

anybody know a way to just get emailed when new versions of Ruby and Rails are released? They have mailing lists and Ruby on Rails has a twitter, but i dont want all the noise that comes with those, i just want to know when a new releases are made, especially ones with security fixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the feed from [the rails blog](https://rubyonrails.org/blog/). https://rubyonrails.org/feed.xml

Answer (score 3):

Follow Rails at VersionEye and you will receive an email as soon the next version will be released.

http://www.versioneye.com/ruby/rails/4.0.0

And You can customize your own RSS Feed to get notified about new versions. Currently you can follow more than 220K open source projects.

By the way. I work at VersionEye. Let me know if you have questions ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to [subscribe to rubyonrails-security](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/rubyonrails-security). There's also [rubyonrails-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/rubyonrails-talk), but that's much noisier.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this service: http://gemnotifier.org/

It will send you an email whenever a new version of a particular gem is released.

Answer (score -1):

You can use IFTTT with "RSS to E-mail"

I have shared a recipe:

https://ifttt.com/recipes/66069

Answer (score -1):

[**Gemnasium**](https://gemnasium.com/) is a great online tool to monitor your project dependencies. You can sync your Github repos or upload Gemfiles of the projects which dependencies you'd like to monitor.